# Where is this Narbonic panel of Dave meeting a female fellow henchman from?

Tags: episode-identification, narbonic

On the TV Tropes page for [Commonality Connection](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CommonalityConnection) (Warning: TVTropes link!), the page image is the following:

[image: Dave meeting a fellow female henchman]

It shows Dave Davenport, of *[Narbonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narbonic)* fame, speaking with a girl named Jamie as they come to the realization that they both hold jobs as henchmen. On that TVTropes page, this is simply linked to the *Narbonic* page, but I don't recognize the panel and my attempts to reverse-image-search or search relevant text isn't helping me much.

Was this one of the paper book bonus story-lines? A dropped story-line? a fan-creation? The font doesn't look quite right for Shaenon's style (too regular, like it's typed in), it's in color which generally only happened for Sunday strips, and the drawing looks too polished for the "drawn on lined notebook paper" style of most of the dropped storyline sketches.

I have a vague memory of, in my last archive trawl of the Director's Cut version, seeing Shaenon mention a planned storyline for Dave finding romance outside of the office before she realized that the Dave-Helen-Lovelace dynamic was enough, but I can't find that reference now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dave's Blind Date](http://narbonic.com/comic/july-2-7-2001/), guest art by Derek Kirk, published July 2001.

Scroll about half-way down the page, or turn the commentary off.

[image]

Comment: And confirmed in a twit by the original author; https://twitter.com/shaenongarrity/status/1021475354064506880

Comment: Thank you. Perception check fail on my part.